# How can I check for existence of an error number?

Tags: sql-server

Is there a way to check if an error number (over 50000) already has been added? I know I can try adding a message and get a 15043 if I re-add an existing message.

Comment: You can check the system view `sys.messages`

Comment: Adding the unique key of `sys.messages` is `message_id,` `language_id`.

Comment: Thanks. If you posted that as an answer I would give you points....

Answer (score 1):

All error messages (system and user defined) are viewable in the system view [sys.messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/messages-for-errors-catalog-views-sys-messages?view=sql-server-ver15).